No -nowarn or -Xlint:none option for java command?
Javac has an option to suppress warnings by passing option -Xlint:none or -nowarn. I run source code without compiling using java command (JEP-330, JEP-458). Is there an option for suppressing warnings in similar way, without modifying source code?
Example source code:
public class UncheckedWarning {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    System.out.println(Object.class.newInstance());
  }
}

terminal:
$ java UncheckedWarning.java
UncheckedWarning.java:3: warning: [deprecation] newInstance() in Class has been deprecated
    System.out.println(Object.class.newInstance());
                                   ^
  where T is a type-variable:
    T extends Object declared in class Class
1 warning
java.lang.Object@3c0a50da


You could redirect stderr to the null device. On Windows this is NUL. On linux, UNIX and MacOS it is /dev/null. For Windows it would be: java UncheckedWarning.java 2>NUL. The warnings will not be displayed since they are written to stderr.

But that would also suppress any System.err.println output.

@k314159 redirect System.err, e.g. System.setErr(System.out);

Sure, but if you're going to change the Java code to do that, then you might as well change the code to fix the deprecation warnings.
